# Merge multiple csv files by using a separate file for the column names using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently trying to merge multiple csv files with missing columns on the other csv. I'm trying to merge them all into one by using a separate file for the column names. This is my code for merging the csv files into one. The problem with this is if a csv file is not in format with the other csv files in terms of columns, it does not append that csv file.

```
def fetch_merge_sheets(input_path, output_path, output_filename):
    input_files = glob.glob(input_path + "/*.csv")
    for file in input_files :
        file_df = pd.read_csv(file)
        merged_data = file_df.append(file_df)
    merged_data.to_csv(output_path + "\\" + output_filename)
```

For example :

```
csv 1:  
col1, col3  
A,B 

csv2:    
col1, col2  
C,D  

csv3:  
col1, col2 
E,F

Column Template :
col1, col2, col3

Actual Result:  
col1, col3  
C,D  
E,F  

Expected Result:  
col1, col2, col3  
A,,B
C,D,
E,F,
```

I fetched all the column names and placed them in a list and after that I don't know what to do.

```
temp_header = pd.read_csv(input_path)
temp_columns = temp_header[temp_column_name].to_list
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `pd.concat`:

```
dfs = []
for file in <list of files> :
    file_df = pd.read_csv(file)
    dfs.append(file_df)
res = pd.concat(dfs, axis=0)
```

The result is:

```
  col1  col3  col2
0    A    B    NaN
0    C   NaN   D  
0    E   NaN     F
```

Comment: Did this answer your question?